# taking picture at a specific time of the day

Tags: android, service, camera, broadcastreceiver

My application should take pictures in background at a specific time of the day. I am going to use AlarmManager but I am wondering whether the class which implements the behavior of my application (i.e., taking a picture) should extend Service or BroadcastReceiver. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You should use IntentSerivce with AlaramManger and define the BroadcastReceiver on your activity.

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
 public static final String URL = "urlpath";
public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
public static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
public static final String RESULT = "result";
public static final String NOTIFICATION = "com.vogella.android.service.receiver";

public DownloadService() {
 super("DownloadService");
}

// Will be called asynchronously be Android
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    fileName);
if (output.exists()) {
  output.delete();
}

InputStream stream = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {

URL url = new URL(urlPath);
stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
  fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
  int next = -1;
  while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
    fos.write(next);
  }
  // Successful finished
  result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (stream != null) {
    try {
      stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  if (fos != null) {
    try {
      fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
publishResults(output.getAbsolutePath(), result);
}

private void publishResults(String outputPath, int result) {
Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, outputPath);
intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
sendBroadcast(intent);
}
} 


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textView;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  if (bundle != null) {
    String string = bundle.getString(DownloadService.FILEPATH);
    int resultCode = bundle.getInt(DownloadService.RESULT);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
          "Download complete. Download URI: " + string,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      textView.setText("Download done");
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download failed",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      textView.setText("Download failed");
    }
  }
}
```

};

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);


 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
 registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadService.NOTIFICATION));
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

public void onClick(View view) {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//   Start every 30 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
}
}
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that when handling a broadcast, the application is given a fixed set of time (currently 10 seconds) in which to do its work. If it doesn't complete in that time, the application is considered to be misbehaving, and its process immediately tossed into the background state to be killed for memory if needed. Based on this, should I use broadcast even if the process of taking a picture and perform some basic manipulation takes more than 10 sec?

Comment: its happen rarely but if you want to do that just ignore sending Broadcast when task take more than 10 sec...

Comment: Returning to your code, does it activate even if the phone is in sleep or deep sleep mode?